# Java MToolkit and XToolkit problems

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, java, xorg

I am attempting to use a Java application (on a linux host) remotely (with X11), and I'm running into problems. The default XToolkit for AWT/Swing seems to have problems with menu alignment (such as reported here: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10724065).

The "quick" solution was to switch back to using the older MToolkit for AWT, by setting AWT_TOOLKIT=sun.awt.motif.MToolkit ... however this comes with it's own set of problems, namely, after a dialog message pops up, keyboard focus is messed up. The caret seems to work properly in however keyboard events aren't generated/received. According to this: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6465038 it seems to have been fixed (a while back) but I am still having this same symptoms even with JRE 1.6.0_20.

Anyone running into the same problems, and, better yet, have a fix/solution?

Answer (score 1):

The link in the question is dead; however, I've had success when connecting to a Linux Java app on the Mac, by simply **un-maximising the application window**. Swing menus then work correctly. (I didn't change the toolkit.)